# From a list, generate a dictionary of each entry's position in the list?

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

Given a list of *distinct items*, I want to get a *dictionary* `lookup` for each element's *index* in the list.

I can write this in normal code like the following:

```
//reference C# pseudocode
interface IThing
{
    int Id {get;}
}

...

List<IThing> things = ...; // guaranteed not to have the same id more than once

...

Dictionary<int, int> lookup = new();

for (int i = 0; i < things.Count; ++i)
    lookup[things[i].Id] = i;
```

I'm fairly sure this can be achieved using *Linq* or *MoreLinq* but I cannot think what it would be called to find the correct extension method. Does this algorithm have a particular name and *is* there something provided... the main issue being that most Linq methods do not tell you the **index** of the item?

Comment: What is wrong with the above code? It is easy to understand and clean way than writing complex linq query, iterating twice to fill the dictionary. I guess your way is better than a linq.

Answer (score 4):

Standard Linq is enough. You can try [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32-1)))) to obtain *both* `item` and its `index` followed by  `.ToDictionary()`:

```
Dictionary<int, int> lookup = things
  .Select((item, index) => (item, index)) // we want both item and its index
  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.item.Id,     // Key is item's id 
                pair => pair.index);      // Value is index
```

Comment: Wow I had no idea you could do that so easily. I used to make an iterator outside the select and `++` it inside the select. Great trick to be able to do it this way.

Comment: I also did not know `Select` could know the index - thanks,